# 2d array pointers - accessing elements and address

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning 2d array pointers and here is my code. I donot know why this line:

```
cout<<"Address of 1st part = "<<*ptr`
```

is not showing an address while this line is showing me address:

```
cout<<"Address of 1st part = "<<*(A)`
```

These both lines means same can any one help me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int A[2][3]={{1,2,4},{5,8,3}};

    int *ptr;
    ptr=&A[0][0];

    cout<<"Address 1st part = "<<A<<endl;
    cout<<"Address 2nd part = "<<A+1<<endl;

    cout<<"Address 1st part = "<<ptr<<endl;
    cout<<"Address 2nd part = "<<ptr+1<<endl;

    cout<<"Address of 1st part = "<<*(A)<<endl;
    cout<<"Address of 1st part = "<<*ptr<<endl;

    cout<<"Address"<<*(A+1)+1<<endl;

    cout<<*(A+1)+2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
Address 1st part = 0x7fffb6c5f660 
Address 2nd part = 0x7fffb6c5f66c 
Address 1st part = 0x7fffb6c5f660 
Address 2nd part = 0x7fffb6c5f664 
Address of 1st part = 0x7fffb6c5f660 
Address of 1st part = 1 
Address0x7fffb6c5f670 
0x7fffb6c5f674
```

Comment: Please narrow it down and show us the output.

Comment: Address 1st part = 0x7fffb6c5f660
Address 2nd part = 0x7fffb6c5f66c
Address 1st part = 0x7fffb6c5f660
Address 2nd part = 0x7fffb6c5f664
Address of 1st part = 0x7fffb6c5f660
Address of 1st part = 1
Address0x7fffb6c5f670
0x7fffb6c5f674

Comment: not in a comment, edit your question and format it properly.

Comment: Because the don't mean the same thing. `*ptr` resolves to type `int`. `*(A)` resolves to type `int (&)[3]`. they're not even close.

Comment: thats what the output is

Comment: I'm telling you your statement "These both lines means same..." is wrong. They're *not* the same.

Comment: can u please give me correction of the line where i made mistake

Comment: Since I don't know what you were *trying* to do, not likely.

Comment: please tell me the declaration of pointer ptr in 2d array. just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two lines do not actually mean the same. A multi-dimensional array is not equivalent to a pointer to its primitive type.

`A` is of type `int [2][3]`, which is equivalent to `int *[3]`. The type of `*A` is `int[3]`, not `int`. The step between successive pointed-to elements, `sizeof *A`, is equal to `sizeof(int)*3`.

`ptr` is of type `int *`. The type of `*ptr` is `int`. The step here, `sizeof *ptr`, is equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Please just correct my code the line .. I just want to understand the declaration pointer variable for 2d array. I understood your point please further explain it.

Comment: You could write `int (*ptr)[3]`, but I'm not entirely sure what you want to do.